# Can I compare two XML files with slightly different structure using XMLUnit?

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I have XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <report>
  <data>
   <table>
    <row>
     <cell name="grouping_type">-1</cell>
     <cell name="book_name">Citygroup</cell>
     <cell name="account"/>
     <cell name="owner_name"/>
    </row>
    <row>
     <cell name="grouping_type">1</cell>
     <cell name="book_name">Citygroup</cell>
     <cell name="account">10933tros_3</cell>
     <cell name="owner_name">10933os</cell>
    </row>
  </table>
 </data>
</report>
```

And another one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <report>
      <data>
       <table>
        <row>
         <cell name="grouping_type">-1</cell>
         <cell name="book_name">Citygroup</cell>
         <cell name="account"/>
         <cell name="ïd"/>
         <cell name="owner_name"/>
        </row>
        <row>
         <cell name="grouping_type">1</cell>
         <cell name="book_name">Citygroup</cell>
         <cell name="account">10933tros_3</cell>
         <cell name="ïd">12</cell>
         <cell name="owner_name">10933os</cell>
        </row>
      </table>
     </data>
    </report>
```

The only difference is additional "cell" element with attribute name="ïd". Can i compare these two XML files using XMLunit so that the only difference was additional "cell" element.

My code is:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc1 = docBuilder.parse(downloadedFile);
        Document doc2 = docBuilder.parse(etalonFile);

        org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff myDiff = new Diff(doc1, doc2);

        DetailedDiff detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(myDiff);
        Iterator<org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Difference> iter = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences().iterator();
        org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Difference diff;
        NodeDetail controlNodeDetail;
        NodeDetail testNodeDetail;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            diff = iter.next();
            controlNodeDetail = diff.getControlNodeDetail();
            System.out.println(diff);
        }
```

XMLUnit compares the "id" cell of the first XML to "owner_name" cell of the second one. Is it possible to solve my issue using XMLUnit?

Comment: Basically, the answer is to normalize the documents before comparison so they compare equal.

Comment: Thanky you, Michael. You mean Ï should remove "ïd" cell before comparison. Good idea!